# How to change the appearance of the display of the first use of an acronym? How to insert "short"?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

How can I change the apperance of the display of the first use of an acronym?

I want to change 
Compact Disc (CD)
to
Compact Disc (short CD)

I tried

```
\defglsdisplayfirst[\acronymtype]{\glsentrylong{\glslabel} (short \glsentryshort{\glslabel})}
```

but this does not work with \glspl because it does not show the plural, if used.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Without a minimal working example, I don't know what settings you are using, but you can define your own custom style like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
  name={\the\glsshorttok},% name is abbreviated form
  description={\the\glslongtok},% description is long form
  first={\the\glslongtok\space(short \the\glsshorttok)},%
  firstplural={\the\glslongtok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix\space(short \the\glsshorttok)},%
  text={\the\glsshorttok},%
  plural={\the\glsshorttok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix}
}

\SetCustomStyle

\newacronym{cd}{CD}{Compact Disc}


\begin{document}

First use: \gls{cd}. Next use: \gls{cd}.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Image of result]